# sql server - setting permissions in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a part of a trigger like so -

```
    DECLARE @isInsert TINYINT

    SET @isInsert = (CASE @actionType WHEN 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

    SELECT
        (CASE @isInsert WHEN 1 THEN i.groupId ELSE d.groupId END) AS groupId
    INTO #tmpRecordPermissionsToCheck
    FROM inserted i
    FULL JOIN deleted d
        ON i.userId = d.userId
            AND
            i.groupId = d.groupId

-- Stop everything if the user is attempting to edit something they're not entitled to...
--   special case(s): refer above for additional tblServer-specific checks required here
    DECLARE @errMsg VARCHAR(255)

    SELECT @errMsg = 'You do not have permission to edit permissions for group ' + IsNULL(ug.shortName, '')
    FROM #tmpRecordPermissionsToCheck tmp
    LEFT JOIN tblUserGroups ug
        ON ug.groupId = tmp.groupId
WHERE dbo.hasAdministrativePermissionsForGroup(tmp.groupId, dbo.getCurrentUser()) = 0


    IF (@errMsg IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ( @errMsg, 16, 1 )
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN
    END
```

I'm calling a separate function that returns a 0 or 1 `bit` value.

If I do `select dbo.isGlobalAdministrator(dbo.getCurrentUser())` I get a 1.

How do I structure the above code so that the `IF (@errMsg IS NOT NULL)` can be overridden if `dbo.isGlobalAdministrator(dbo.getCurrentUser()) = 1` ?

Comment: You have an issue with the overall structure here. You are assuming there will only every be a single row in the inserted or deleted tables. This is not the case.

Comment: I'm reverse engineering current logic.  As far as I'm to understand there is only ever a single row.  The overall trigger is based on when a single record is inserted, updated or deleted

Comment: You are designing your trigger with a very brittle view of it. In sql server a trigger is fired once per operation, not once per row. If you need to do some maintenance and update 2 rows with a single update statement your trigger logic is not going to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do I structure the above code so that the IF (@errMsg IS NOT NULL) can be overridden if dbo.isGlobalAdministrator(dbo.getCurrentUser()) = 1 ?

When you say overridden,i think you want to bypass errormessage

so just add  this above error message

```
if ( dbo.isGlobalAdministrator(dbo.getCurrentUser()) = 1)
return
```